# Power BI Rolling 12 Months nothing to calcuate?

Tags: powerbi, measure

I have an access database I am pulling data from. It has data going back to 2015 but I only want the data from the most complete 12 months. Today is 9/27/2021 so I would want data from September 2020 to August of 2021.

Sample data:

| Date | Level |
| --- | --- |
| 8/12/2019 | Level 1 |
| 1/26/2021 | Level 3 |
| 6/13/2020 | Level 4 |
| 4/12/2021 | Level 1 |
| 3/7/2015 | Level 2 |
| 4/16/2021 | Level 2 |

I want a simple bar chart where it has the month/year and the count per level

Comment: Is [relative date filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range) sufficient for your use case?

Comment: no, this wont group them by month, unless there is a work around?

Comment: Filtering and grouping are two separate things. For grouping you probably want something like a [date hierarchy](https://5minutebi.com/2017/11/29/how-to-use-powerbi-date-hierarchy/).

Comment: Yes i understand that. The idea of this is that people enter data into this access database every day. sometime during the month, I want to open this up, hit refresh and it will only show the most recent complete 12 months of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative date filtering `is in the last` `12` `calendar months`.

Here's what that looks like for today (9/28/2021):

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Click your visualization on power bi desktop, expand date filter,

[image]

add 1 year

[image]

or you can add filter from transform data tab in power bi desktop

Comment: this worked great. but now my visualization only shows events per day. I still need them clustered by month

Comment: you can add months for x axis, if not add another column for months from transform data tab, plz give upvote if this works